# Flood myth = Maritime Voyages & Colonization Interpretation?

Tags: comparative, interpretation, flood-myth

I am currently studying various flood myths from all around the world.
I interprete this whole story as a maritime voyage & colonization story:

The ark is simply a ship (bigger than a cockleshell; with roof/deck). 
The flood is the sea. Land drowns below the horizon (even mountains) when leaving the coast. Where was once land (around you) is now water.
The old world is destroyed by leaving it, the new world is populated by the maritime explorers. The "old world" an increasingly unpleasant place due to overpopulation etc. is a very good reason to leave it.
When you want to colonize, you take things with you that allow you to build a settlement. This also includes (small) livestock.

But my question is:

Are there any known interpretations of the flood myth to **not** be a literal flood but a maritime voyage / colonization?

I searched for it, but **everyone** seems to take the word "flood" literal.

Does this interpretation maybe have a name I can use to search for it?

Comment: My sense has always been that back in prehistory there was a single ginormous flood event that was so massive it imprinted itself on every surviving human culture, and was written into many mythologies. I find your colonization theory intriguing, but I haven't heard anything in that direction myself either.

Comment: The closest to my maritime seafaring interpretation I found so far is a book called "Eden in the East" by Stephen Oppenheimer. He postulates a drowned continent in south east asia that was early populated. The flooding of the continent due to glacial melting after ice age resulted in lots of migrations from there to all over the world, taking flood myths with them. Interesting book that even contains lots of sources.

Comment: @Gibet is synthesizing an interpretation, not personally insofar many believe that was how the tablet began, but the beginning is missing and only interpolated from later texts.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this interpretation makes sense. For one thing, there are plenty of "colonization" stories where people go on ocean voyages. I can't think of a single instance where land is described as "drowning" as people move away from the coastline.

> The old world is destroyed by leaving it, the new world is populated by the maritime explorers. The "old world" an increasingly unpleasant place due to overpopulation etc. is a very good reason to leave it.

You're essentially describing the biblical story of Noah. There are lots of other flood stories.

> I searched for it

take a look at the book *The Flood Myth* by Alan Dundes. It's a collection of academic essays on flood stories from around the world. I think you will find it helpful and interesting. (I've never read it but I've heard good things about it, and I'm a fan of the author.)

> My sense has always been that back in prehistory there was a single ginormous flood event that was so massive it imprinted itself on every surviving human culture, and was written into many mythologies

There are more plausible explanations for the prevalence of certain motifs across cultures.

Comment: When I came to look into your suggested book and it contains clues to colonization interpretation I will accept the answer.

btw: I know of lots of the other stories I just used the most common one to describe my idea =)

Comment: @xaedes Have you actually read the book yet? Or are you saying that you will read the book in the future?

Comment: I couldnt grab a copy of it yet! Ordered it, but due to global shipping it will arrive not until the end of the month. If someone with the book can tell me whether my non-literal interpretation is somehow included I could mark the answer as accepted. Otherwise it will take some time^^ Btw, the author is correctly called "Alan Dundes"

Comment: @xaedes what if the book argues *against* your non-literal interpretation? In fact, I would be shocked if the book offers any evidence to support your theory.

Comment: then it wouldn't really answer my question

Comment: @xaedes just curious: do you think it's possible that your theory is incorrect? What evidence would you need to convince yourself that your theory is incorrect?

Comment: it is an interpretation that is very obvious to me. I dont necessarily want to turn in it into an historical fact or scientific valid theory. But I can't be the only one that draws similar conclusions I did. I dont concern myself too much to prove it wrong; but I look for clues and others that interprete it similar. If it turns out that I REALLY am the only one that came up with this interpretation (then my original question here can't be answered) I will someday put everything together and put it out in the world.